# PHP folder permissions problem

Tags: php, linux, file-permissions

I am trying to create a folder and then another folder within it using PHP.

If this is the directory structure I have

```
/home/site                           (owner : user1)
```

Now, I create the folder using

```
mkdir("/home/site/newdir",0777);     (user : apache)
```

The directory **/home/site/newdir** is created but the user of that directory is "*apache*"

Now, doing

```
mkdir("/home/site/newdir/anotherdir",0777);
```

doesnt create another directory inside newdir.

Please help. I think its a owner issue. **I cannot change the owner using chmod() either**. The owner remains the same.

What might be causing this ?

**EDIT :**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

mkdir("./m",0777);  // works
mkdir("./m/v",0777); // doesnt work
```

And no errors on the page.

```
var_dump(is_writeable("./m")) // returns bool(true)
```

**EDIT :** This has been fixed. For others who might be facing the same issue, It was because of PHP's safe mode being "on". Still dont know the reason behind what exactly does safe mode do that doesnt let you create nested directories.

But it works now. Thanks all for reading.

Comment: You are creating the directory with 0777 permissions, this must not be a permissions problem. Does PHP display any error when trying to create a directory inside /home/site/newdir ?

Comment: No errors. var_dump(is_writeable("./m")) returns true. Check my edited post.

Comment: What about `mkdir("./m/v", 0777, true);`?

Comment: Fixed. Please check original post. Thanks all for helping out.

Comment: Note: `chmod` can never change the owner of a file or directory, that's not what it does. `chown` does that, but under any reasonable server setup, you won't be able to actually use it (you need to be root).

Comment: Also, you should post an answer of your own if you figure out the solution to your problem, not just edit the question.

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem and I don't want to disable the PHP safe mode. Do you know any other solution, or which settings of PHP I should change?

Answer (score 1):

The mode on the directory created by `mkdir()` is affected by your current umask, which is why `chmod()` is not working for you.

Try:

```
$old_mask = umask(0);
mkdir("/home/site/newdir/anotherdir",0777);
umask($old_mask);
```